# Compare substrings of different columns

Tags: dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark

I have a dataframe like this:

```
+----------------------+--------------------------------------------------+-------------------+
| column_1             |column_2|                                         |Required_column    |
+----------------------+--------------------------------------------------+-------------------+
|K12B-45-84-6          |K12B-02-36-504, I05O-21-65-312, A301-21-25-363    | True              |
|J020-35-2-9           |P12K-05-31-602, M002-22-22-636,L630-51-32-544     | False             | 
|L006-85-00-694        |M10P-22-94-349,L006-85-00-694, I553-35-12-240     | True              |
|M002-22-36-989        |U985-12-45-363,    M002-19-14-964                 | True              |
+----------------------+--------------------------------------------------+-------------------+
```

Explaination: column_1 and column_2 are a string,
for easy understanding let us call the values in the dataframe as "switch".
Column_1 always has only one switch value per row but column_2 may have multiple switch values in it. The value should be returned True or False only by comparing the first 4 strings(ex: K12B == K12B see row one)

Note: Even though the switch values in column_2 are comma seperated, there is never a common logic(sometimes there maybe a space or two spaces etc)
The hint is every switch value either in column_1 or column_2 starts with a letter, Therefore a logic is required based on that hint

The aim is to have the required column which either returns True or False, The solution is required in Pyspark

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution using Pyspark's [substring](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.1.1/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.functions.substring.html) and [contains](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.1.1/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.Column.contains.html?highlight=contains#pyspark.sql.Column.contains) functions. In this way, you don't have to worry about cleanliness of `column_2`, you just need to be sure that `column_1` is cleaned:

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

data = [
    ("K12B-45-84-6", "K12B-02-36-504, I05O-21-65-312, A301-21-25-363"),
    ("J020-35-2-9", "P12K-05-31-602, M002-22-22-636,L630-51-32-544"),
    ("L006-85-00-694", "M10P-22-94-349,L006-85-00-694, I553-35-12-240"),
    ("M002-22-36-989", "U985-12-45-363,    M002-19-14-964")]

columns = ["column_1", "column_2"]
df = spark.createDataFrame(data = data, schema = columns)


df = df.withColumn("Required_column", F.when(
            F.col("column_2").contains(F.substring(F.col("column_1"), 1, 4)), True
        ).otherwise(False)
            )
df.show()
```

Output:

```
+--------------+--------------------+---------------+
|      column_1|            column_2|Required_column|
+--------------+--------------------+---------------+
|  K12B-45-84-6|K12B-02-36-504, I...|           true|
|   J020-35-2-9|P12K-05-31-602, M...|          false|
|L006-85-00-694|M10P-22-94-349,L0...|           true|
|M002-22-36-989|U985-12-45-363,  ...|           true|
+--------------+--------------------+---------------+
```